# Base64 string only works in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, base64

I have a base64 svg string that will not work in FF or Safari, yet works great in Chrome. (lastest versions) The error I am receiving in FF is: [image: Whyyyyyy?]

My css looks like:

```
.icon.icon-play {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;\a base64, 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");
}
```

I am not sure on where to go from here, except for just rebasing the images. Which I cannot do at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on Firefox (even if I leave in the extraneous \a). Here's it without though...

```css
.icon {
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
  width: 101px;
  height: 128px;
}

You seem to have some extraneous %20 characters and a \a character. %20
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```